# Finding the index of a string inside a field of strings

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

My apologies for a very basic question, I'm new to Rcpp and c++ from R.

I have a field (`arma::field`) which I have initialized to hold strings (`arma::field<std::string> my_vector`). I also have a string `std::string id` that is somewhere inside the field of strings, and I would like the find the position of where it is. I'm used to doing this with vectors and numbers similar to below:

```cpp
arma::vec fun(arma::vec input_vector){

    // Find where vector equals 5 (for example)
    uvec index = arma::find(input_vector == 5);

    return index;
}
```

I initially tried to do the exact same thing, but given a string instead of number to compare:

```cpp
arma::uvec fun(arma::vec input_vector, std::string id){

    // Find where vector string id
    uvec index = arma::find(input_vector == id);

    return index;
}
```

This returns an error

```cpp
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('arma::vec' (aka 'Col<double>') 
    and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'))
```

which made sense because the vector was not initialized to contain strings. Though I don't think that the vector can be initialized to contain strings, because when I tried `arma::vec<std::string>`, it gives a mess of errors.

This lead me to fields which can hold a lot more kinds of variables.

```cpp
arma::uvec fun(arma::field<std::string> input_field, std::string id){

    // Find where vector equals 5 (for example)
    uvec index = arma::find(input_field == id);

    return index;
}
```

However this returns

```cpp
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('arma::field<std::string>' and
      'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'))
```

I have tried `strcmp` as well, which also threw an error

```cpp
error: no viable conversion from 'arma::field<std::string>' to 'const char *'
```

This leads me to ask, how can I find the position of a string within a field?

I'm open to changing the types around to something that works better, I suspect that using `std::vector` might work better or perhaps a different kind that I haven't heard of. However, my first experiments haven't been very successful. If anyone has any hints on which direction to go, it would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Clarified that `find` was `arma::find` instead of `std::find` as it was very not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arma` does not support the storage of `std::string` within its data structures per [Matrix types](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat)

> The root matrix class is Mat, where type is one of:
>
> - float, double, std::complex, std::complex, short, int, long, and unsigned versions of short, int, long

In turn, `Rcpp` does not support the import or export of `std::vector<std::string>` into `armadillo`. Thus, the error.

The easiest way to find a string in this case is to loop through the vector and check each element. Alternatively, make a map and see if the key is within the map.

Loop string checking approach:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> find_string_locs(std::vector<std::string> input_vector, std::string id)
{
  std::vector<int> id_locs; // Setup storage for found IDs

  for(int i =0; i < input_vector.size(); i++) // Loop through input
    if(input_vector[i] == id) // check if input matches target
      id_locs.push_back(i);

    return id_locs; // send locations to R (c++ index shift!)
}

/***R
input_vector = c("stat","toad","stat","rcpp")
id = "stat"
find_string_locs(input_vector,id)
*/
```

The output is then:

```
[1] 0 2
```

Note the C++ index shift... Starts at 0 instead of 1 like in R.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This portion of the code is within a decent sized loop, so though looping through each element definitely sounds like a viable solution, though probably not in this case. I will look into the key / map idea. All the best.

Comment: @ChrisC I'll revisit this later today with a code example. Also, loops in C++ are **not** evil.

Comment: Appreciate the help, @Coatless. No rush at all, I'm sure you're quite busy with your own stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Coatless, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what, Coatless said, I'm not sure, you understand the use of a vector in C++. In C++, a vector merely a re-sizable list.

With respect to vectors of algebra, it has a magnitude (size) but it does not really have a direction. In other words, it is not a vector in the algebraic sense.

If you would like to search a std::vector for a string, you may do so like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int get_str_position(const std::string& str_to_find, const std::vector<std::string>& vector_to_search)
{
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = std::find(vector_to_search.begin(), vector_to_search.end(), str_to_find);

    if (it == vector_to_search.end()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return it - vector_to_search.begin();
    }
};

void find_str(const std::string& str_to_find, const std::vector<std::string>& vector_to_search)
{
    int position = get_str_position(str_to_find, vector_to_search);

    if (position == -1) {
        std::cout << "Could not find string: '" << str_to_find << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Found string '" << str_to_find << "' at position " << position << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "one", "two", "three" };

    std::string existent_str = "two";
    std::string non_existent_str = "four";

    find_str(existent_str, vec);
    find_str(non_existent_str, vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
Found string 'two' at position 1
Could not find string: 'four'
```

Further, in your function 'fun', you say:

```
arma::uvec fun(arma::field<std::string> input_field, std::string id){

    // Find where vector equals 5 (for example)
    uvec index = find(input_field == id);

    return index;
}
```

If you are using std::find, you will only be searching 'input_field' for a value of 0 or 1, since you pass a boolean expression as an argument to find...

```
// Not sure how this works at all
// You should not be able to compare a string to a std::vector<std::string>
bool true_or_false = (input_field == id); 


// Find 0 (false) or 1 (true)
uvec index = find(true_or_false);
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent, you're entirely correct that I don't really understand C++! Thank you so much for the code and the effort you put into it, I'll take a closer look and try to implement it into my own.  Though it's impossible that you could have known this, the `find` function was actually `arma::find` as opposed to `std::find`. That still doesn't make what I did correct, but perhaps sheds some light on the logic. Regardless, thanks for your help, it was very useful.

Comment: The OP is using http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find not `std::find`